# How to make turn.js not capturing the mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mousewheel

I have made a sell page ([here](http://elie.elieserrats.com/)) with [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/) (the [zoom](http://www.turnjs.com/samples/magazine/) version) and [openElement](http://www.openelement.com/). Since I have added turn.js, I cannot scroll the page anymore with the mouse wheel (the former version without turn.js is [here](http://elieserrats.com)). It is liked turn.js had "captured" this event and don't pass it to the browser.

The html content used as the page index in the turn.js example is embedded in an openElement "elements panel" block of code, so it is included in index.html at some place in the hierarchy.

I am a web designer newbie. Your investigation ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [openElement forum](http://forum.openelement.com/fr/forum_posts.asp?TID=19973&PN=2&title=ascenseur-de-dfilement-de-page) (in french), I put the turn.js flipbook in an iframe.